# Epsilon-Delta analysis for the Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Law of Large Numbers: For a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$, each with an expected value $E[X_i] = \mu$ and sample estimator $\overline{X_n}$ =  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{{i=1}}^{n} x_i$ :

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \overline{X_n} - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon \right) = 0$$

**My Question:** Provided $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$ are all iid and all come from some specific Probability Distribution Function $g(x; \theta)$ : What value of $n$ is required to "probabilistically" achieve a certain value of $\epsilon$?

As an example, suppose I have 100 randomly generated iid data points. I believe these points  came from a Normal Distribution.  Suppose there was some "magic" way of knowing that these $n$ = 100 data points were actually generated from  a Normal Distribution with $\mu=5$,$\sigma=5$ .

Then, on average (i.e. if we had access to the infinite universe of all samples of size $n$ = 100 from a Normal Distribution with $\mu=5$,$\sigma=5$ ) : For $n$ = 100, what would be the average value of $\epsilon$?

Can this be answered using Cramer's Theorem of Large Deviations? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)?

Thanks!

- Note: For $n$ = 100 ,would this average value of $\epsilon$ vary for different Normal Distributions? e.g. ($\mu=5$,$\sigma=5$) vs ($\mu=2$,$\sigma=3$)
- For $n$ = 100, would this average value of $\epsilon$ vary for different Probability Distributions Functions? e.g.  Normal Distribution vs Exponential Distribution vs Gamma Distirbution, etc?

Follow up Question: [Applying Hoeffding's Inequality in Real Life](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836210/applying-hoeffdings-inequality-in-real-life)

Comment: If $X_i$ are normally distributed it is easy: $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is $N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. If $X_i$ are not normal, but are bounded, then you don't have specific distribution info on $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ but you can use the Chernov-Hoeffding bound (look on wikipedia). If all you have are the $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ parameters you can use the Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: @Michael: thank you so much for your reply! I will read about the Chernov-Hoeffding bound

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems that the Chernov-Hoeffding bound is for the "theoretical" random variable (i.e. does not depend on the observed random sample $x_1, x_2... x_n$). Therefore, is this concept still applicable in my problem?

Comment: That is not a correct interpretation. Chernov-Hoeffding is what you want. Your samples are random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$. I do not know what you mean by a "theoretical random variable." I would suggest never using small-case $x_i$ when you are talking about a random variable $X_i$. Chernov-Hoeffing requires the random variables to be bounded so that $a\leq X_i\leq b$ for all $i$ (surely). An example is $X_i \sim Unif[a,b]$ or $X_i \sim Bern(1/2)$ (where $a=0,b=1$).

Comment: @ Michael: thank you so much for your reply! What I meant by "theoretical random variable". I was not sure if the Chernov-Hoeffding bound is applicable for finite sample settings  .... or if the  Chernov-Hoeffding bound is only intended for infinite samples. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$.  Define the random variable:
$$M_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

**Claim 1:** For all $n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have $E[M_n]=\mu$ and $Var(M_n)=\sigma^2/n$.

**Claim 2 (Normal):** If $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $M_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$. If we define $G \sim N(0,1)$ then $M_n-\mu$ has the same distribution as $\frac{G\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and
$$ P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon] = P\left[|\frac{G\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}| \geq \epsilon\right] = P\left[|G|\geq \frac{\epsilon \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\right] = 2Q\left(\frac{\epsilon\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\right)$$
where $Q(\cdot)$ is the Gaussian tail function.

**Claim 3 (Bounded):** If $a\leq X_i\leq b$ almost surely then the Hoeffding inequality here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

says
$$P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon] \leq 2\exp\left(\frac{-2n\epsilon^2}{(b-a)^2}\right)$$
where I am using the wikipedia formula with $M_n=S_n/n$ and $t=n\epsilon$.

**Claim 4 (General):** If $X_i$ are not bounded and you don't know the distribution, all you can use is the Chebyshev inequality
$$ P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon] \leq \frac{\sigma^2/n}{\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: @ Michael: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: 1) When you start the question, in the initial definition of $X_i$, we assume i goes from 1 to infinity. But $M_n$ is based on a finite sample, correct?

Comment: 2) In Claim 3, by the word "bounded", you mean $X_i$ has finite variance?  In Claim 4, by the word "unbounded", you mean $X_i$ has infinite variance? Correct?

Comment: 3) In all 4 claims .... Calculating the term $ P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon]$ requires either knowledge of the true $\mu$ or an assumption as to what the true value of $\mu$ is. Correct?

Comment: 4) Why does Claim 3 require knowledge of the probability distribution for X ... but Claim 4 does not require knowledge of the probability distribution for X? Looking at the equations, I can't understand why one of them requires knowledge of the probability distribution and the other does not

Comment: 5) Last question - how we use these claims practically?  suppose we consider Claim 3.  Case 1: I observe $n$ data points - using this data, I can calculate $M_n$.  I pick some arbitrary values of $a$ and $b$, and I also pick some value of $\epsilon$. Can I solve for $\mu$? Case 2: Suppose I assume I know $M_n$,  pick some $\epsilon$, and I assume the true $\mu$. Can I solve for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: btw: I posted a follow up question over here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836210/applying-hoeffdings-inequality-in-real-life

Comment: Briefly: 1 Yes; 2 No; 3 No; 4 It doesn't; 5 You cannot pick arbitrary $a,b$ in Claim 3.

Comment: A random variable $X_i$ takes values in some bounded interval $[a,b]$ if $X$ can never be larger than $b$ or smaller than $a$. Examples are $X \sim Unif[a,b]$ or $X$ with some PDF with support only on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: If it helps you can note that $$P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon] = P[M_n-\epsilon \leq \mu \leq M_n+\epsilon]$$ So you can view $[M_n-\epsilon, M_n+\epsilon]$ as a confidence interval for the unknown value of $\mu$.

Comment: Example: Suppose $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P[X_i=1]=\mu$ and $P[X_i=0]=1-\mu$, but $\mu$ is unknown. This is the bounded case with $a=0, b=1$. Let's fix $\epsilon = 1/100$. How many samples do we need to get a confidence interval $[M_n-\epsilon, M_n+\epsilon]$ that contains $\mu$ with probability at least $0.95$? We know $P[|M_n-\mu|\geq 1/100] \leq 2\exp(-2n/100^2)$, to make this value less than $1-0.95$ we need $n=18445$ samples. The reason we need so many samples is that we have made our confidence interval width very small ($2\epsilon = 2/100$).