# Applying Hoeffding's Inequality in Real Life Situations

Tags: probability

Recently, I posted this question here [Epsilon-Delta analysis for the Law of Large Numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835885/epsilon-delta-analysis-for-the-law-of-large-numbers) where I learned about Hoeffding's Inequality (from this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835891/791334):

> Fix $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with
> mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$.  Define the random variable:
> $$M_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
>
> **Claim 3 (Bounded):** If $a\leq X_i\leq b$ almost surely then the Hoeffding inequality here:
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality
>
> says $$P[|M_n-\mu|\geq \epsilon] \leq
>  2\exp\left(\frac{-2n\epsilon^2}{(b-a)^2}\right)$$ where I am using the
> wikipedia formula with $M_n=S_n/n$ and $t=n\epsilon$.

**My Question:** I am wondering how to apply Hoeffding's Inequality to real world situations.

Here are my ideas so far: Suppose I observe $n$ data points - using this data, I can calculate $M_n$. Therefore, I know $n$ and  $M_n$.

- Case 1:  I pick some values of $a$ and $b$, and I also pick some value of $\epsilon$. Can I solve for $\mu$?
- Case 2: I pick some $\epsilon$, and I assume the true $\mu$. Can I solve for $a$ and $b$?

Based on these cases:

- In Case 1, I now know that $ 2\exp\left(\frac{-2n\epsilon^2}{(b-a)^2}\right) = p_1$ . So this would be like saying: Based on $M_n$ calculated from my data, what value(s) of $\mu$ will result in a $p_1$ probability of |$M_n$ - $\mu$| being greater than equal to some chosen value $\epsilon$? But this does not seem to useful because there could be many values of $\mu$ that satisfy this inequality ...and I might end up with some very desirable probability , but this probability would not reflect the true $\mu$ , thus not being very useful.
- In Case 2, I am saying the opposite. Provided I have knowledge of the true $\mu$ (or assume the true value of $\mu$), what values of $a$ and $b$ would result in the probability $P[|M_n-\mu|$ being greater than some chosen value $\epsilon$? However, I anticipate there again might be multiple values of  $a$ and $b$ that will satisfy this.
- "Case 3": Perhaps there might be another way to analyze Case 2. That is, if I also pick some specific values of $a$ and $b$, I might be able to calculate the exact probability of $|M_n-\mu$ being greater than some chosen $\epsilon$?

**Can someone please help me understand how Hoeffding's Inequality can be applied in real life?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Quick note, separate from the main point: You can't/shouldn't "pick" or "solve for" $a,b$. In order to apply this inequality, you must *a priori* know (based on knowledge of the population, **not** knowledge of the sample) that there exist some numbers $a,b$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_1\geqslant a)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1\leqslant b)=1$. Realized sample values can never tell you this.

If you do know from the population that such $a,b$ exist, then you would always want to choose the biggest $a$ which makes $\mathbb{P}(X_1\geqslant a)=1$ hold, and the smallest $b$ which makes $\mathbb{P}(X_1\leqslant b)=1$ hold. In other words, you choose the (essential) min and max of the distribution. If the $X_i$ are $\pm 1$, you would choose $a=-1$ and $b=1$. The result would still be true if you picked $a=-2$ and $b=5$, for example, but you would simply get a looser inequality. As another example, suppose $X_i$ takes values in $\{-1,0,1\}$, each with positive probability. If you observe a sample, there is a chance you will see only $0$ and $1$, and if you only look at the sample, you might erroneously think you can choose $a=0$. This is why you can't choose $a,b$ based on the sample alone.

**The values $a,b$ have optimal choices which depend on the actual populations, and which can't be known based on the sample alone.**

=========================================================================
You can never solve for $\mu$ based on a sample alone. Generally, what we have is an error tolerance $\theta>0$, a probability tolerance $\alpha\in (0,1)$, and an estimate $\hat{\mu}$ of the true mean $\mu$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(\hat{\mu}-\theta\leqslant \mu\leqslant \hat{\mu}+\theta)>1-\alpha.$$ So we don't end up knowing $\mu$, but we have an estimate $\hat{\mu}$ which we are really confident (as quantified by $\alpha$) is really close (as quantified by $\theta$) to the true value. So the mean is probably in this very tiny window. In your case, $M_n$ will be your estimate (or estimator) $\mu{hat}$. There are other ways to estimate the mean, though, so $\hat{\mu}$ need not always be the sample mean.

Of course, "really confident" and "really close" are relative and subjective. Chebyshev's inequality, for example, says that for $\theta>0$, $$\mathbb{P}(|M_n-\mu|\geqslant \theta)\leqslant \frac{\sigma^2}{n\theta^2},$$ without any assumptions about the $a,b$, and we can use $\sigma^2/n\theta^2$ as our $\alpha$. In practice, we always perform a balancing act between $\theta$ and $\alpha$. Tighter intervals are better, but necessarily come with less confidence that the tighter intervals contain the true mean. For example, you want to know how to dress for tomorrow's weather. I'm $99.999999\%$ sure that tomorrow's temperature will be between $-200^\circ C$ and $+200^\circ C$. Does the fact that I'm very confident make this a useful estimate? No, because the window is too wide to convey useful information about $\mu$, tomorrow's expected temperature. On the other hand, let's say I'm $0.000001\%$ sure that tomorrow' temperature will be between $21^\circ C$ and $21.001^\circ C$. If the temperature is in that window, you know exactly how to dress, but I'm not very certain the temperature will actually be in that window. So you can't say with high certainty that you should dress for a temperature in this range. So in practice, we can wiggle $\theta$ around as a parameter and see, for each $\theta$, what is the optimal $\alpha$, and see if we can find a combination that yields a window that is acceptably small while still maintaining an acceptably large amount of confidence that the true mean is in that window. Another approach, common in hypothesis testing, would be to look at specific benchmarks, say $\alpha=1\%$, $5\%$, or $10\%$, and pick the optimal $\theta$. One last approach, if you have the luxury of choosing your own sample, could say you have beforehand a required $\theta$ and $\alpha$ (for example, I want to get an estimate $\hat{\mu}$ such that I'm $95\%$ confident that tomorrow's temperature is $\hat{\mu} \pm 2.5^\circ C$, so I require $\alpha = 5\%$ and $\theta=2.5^\circ C$). Then we can ask: What is the minimum sample size that will let me achieve this $\alpha$ and $\theta$?

The point of Hoeffding's inequality is that, under the stronger assumption that there exist $a,b$ such that $\mathbb{P}(a\leqslant X_1\leqslant b)=1$, we can use $\alpha = 2\exp(-2n\theta^2/(b-a)^2)$. This often gives a much, much tighter bound than you could get from weaker assumptions. For example, Chebyshev has behavior that's asymptotically like $1/n$, so it goes to zero polynomially in the sample size, whereas Hoeffding's gives something that goes exponentially to zero as the sample size grows. In practice, the main thing you would do with this is simply get better combinations of $\theta$ and $\alpha$. This is most relevant when you are in the third situation from the last paragraph: What is the minimum sample size $n$ that would allow me to get an estimate that's in line with some pre-determined $\alpha$ and $\theta$? The optimal dependence on $\theta$ aside, we can say that, for example, Chebyshev's inequality gives sample size $n\approx C/\alpha$ (where $C$ depends on $\theta$, $\sigma$) and Hoeffding gives something like $C'\log(1/\alpha)$, where $C'$ depends on $\theta, a,b$. Here, $C,C'$ are different for the two methods. For some values of $\alpha$, we won't necessarily know which method is better, but for fixed $\theta,\sigma,a,b$, we know that asymptotically Hoeffding will perform better.

=========================================================================

More generally, Hoeffding's inequality is an example of a concentration inequality (that is, an instance of what is known as the concentration of measure phenomenon). There are a number of natural situations in which there exist a family $(\Omega_n, \Sigma_n, \mathbb{P}_n)$ of probability spaces and constants $\phi,\psi>0$ such that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, any $\theta>0$, any $L$-Lipschitz function $f:\Omega_n\to \mathbb{R}$ and any $M$ such that $\mathbb{P}_n(f\geqslant M)\geqslant 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}_n(f\leqslant M)\geqslant 1/2$, it holds that $$\mathbb{P}_n(|f-M|\geqslant \theta L)\leqslant \phi \exp(-\psi n\theta^2).$$  This is a concentration result, saying that $f$ is tightly concentrated around $M$. Such results can often (in every case I know of) be reformulated so that $M$ can be replaced with the mean of $f$, possibly with replacing $\phi,\psi$ with other constants. So essentially we'd think about $\mathbb{P}_n(|f-\mathbb{E}f|>\theta L)\leqslant \phi\exp(-\psi n\theta^2)$. Here, $\phi,\psi$ don't depend on $n$, so this probability goes to zero exponentially as sample size grows.

For example, let $\Omega_n=\mathbb{R}^n$, endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_n$. For $B\in \mathcal{B}_n$, let $\mathbb{P}_n(B)=\mathbb{P}((X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in B)$, where $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are the iid random variables from your question. Define $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. This is $1$-Lipschitz (so $L=1$), and we see Hoeffding's inequality is an example of this type with $\phi=2$ and $\psi=2/(b-a)^2$.

Concentration of measure also holds on the Hamming cubes, spheres in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Haar measure, gaussian measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. More generally, this type of inequality can be obtained for random vectors whose entries are independent with uniformly bounded subgaussian constants. That is, if $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ are independent, mean zero (not necessarily identically distributed) random variables, and if there exists a constant $K>0$ such that for any $j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\theta>0$, $$\mathbb{P}(|Y_j|\geqslant \theta)\leqslant 2\exp(-\theta^2/K^2),$$ then the measures $\mathbb{P}_n$ defined on $\Omega_n=\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\mathbb{P}_n(B)=\mathbb{P}((Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B)$ also satisfy this type of result, where $\phi,\psi$ will depend on $K$.

There are a number of applications of these types of results. These kind of stand on the border between practical and theoretical, in the sense that they can be used to prove a theorem/bound, which has further practical applications. For example, the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma says that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that if we have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$, there exists a function $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$(1-\varepsilon)\|u-v\|^2\leqslant \|G(u)-G(v)\|^2\leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\|u-v\|^2,$$ where $u,v$ are any of our $n$ points, as long as $n>\frac{C}{\varepsilon^2}\log(n)$. So if we don't care about the points themselves, but only the distances between them, and we're okay distorting those distances by not more than a fixed error tolerance (depending on $\varepsilon$), we can go from dimension $n$ to dimension on the order of $\log(n)$, which is a huge reduction. Modern proofs use concentration of measure and produce a linear $G$ (although Johnson and Lindenstrauss, I believe, did not prove this using concentration and did not get a linear $G$). It is worth noting that you cannot possibly hope for a linear $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m<n$ (that is, a linear map that reduces the dimension at all) that preserves all distances, because it must send some non-zero vectors to zero. So it really is the case that $G$ doesn't preserve all distances between all pairs, and that preserving between pairs of our $n$ points is kind of the best we could hope for in this situation.

The Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma and a number of its spiritual descendants are of this type and are of significant practice in signal processing/compressed sensing/computer science, namely because it allows for drastic reduction in memory requirements while losing very little information. Other applications, such as the existence of RIP matrices (restricted isometry property) and sparse recovery might allow for something similar to Johnson-Lindenstrauss: We get $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $G$ linear and $m\ll n$ which preserve lengths of all $k$-sparse vectors (ignore what this means for the moment), and in fact for any $k$-sparse vector $v$, if we know $Gv$, we can exactly recover $v$. So there is no information loss, if we only care about $k$-sparse vectors. Again, we absolutely cannot expect to be able to recover $v$ from $Gv$ for each $v$ when $m<n$, because there will be infinitely many $v$ such that $Gv=0$.

I'm throwing some links below, but concentration of measure, the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma, and the results which have come after, have inspired lots of nice, accessible papers which give overviews, practical applications, etc. I would recommend checking out a few expository papers. These may have better insights into practical applications and give a good intuition for this family of results.

[Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05448.pdf)

[Sparse recovery](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eecprice/courses/sublinear/bwca-sparse-recovery.pdf)

[Concentration of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure)

Comment: wow! thank you so much for this detailed answer! I will take some time to digest and understand it. Just a question (I made a small edit to my original question) - based on what you have written, is Case 3 the most realistic use case of Hoeffdings Inequality in real world situations? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am now going to work on a Python/R simulation to see if it is possible to visualize the results of Hoeffdings Inequality ! :)

Comment: I think Case 3 might be correct? it seems the "lowest risk" approach ...

Comment: In real-world situations, my guess is that there would be two main users: Designers of experiments, and analyzers of experiments. Analyzers often times have to work with the dataset they are given, and they don't have the luxury/ability (or, often, the budget) to choose $n$. They don't have the option of $3$. They would build confidence intervals, and they would typically use Hoeffding to get a better combination of $\theta$ and $\alpha$ with the $n$ they were handed (Case $2$). For designers of experiments, yes, I believe Case $3$ would be the common application.